# cmake - get the used commandline flags "-D"

Tags: cmake

i recently switched a few projects from autotools to cmake.

one common thing i liked on autotools is that - if i go into the src build directory. there is config.log/config.status - where at the top the `./configure --params` command is listed - so it is easy to rerun the former used commandline flags.

(like after compiling some stuff - i want to add a another `--enable-this` - so copy & paste from config.log/status - and rerun the `./configure --old-params --enable-this`)

in cmake - i have a bunch of  `-D` flags - how can i find the used commandline like in config.log/status - with a cmake project?

i know there is the CMakeCache... - but its hard to extract the used flags

**edit:**

i came up with the following solution:

```
#save commandline to rebuild this :)
set(USED_CMD_LINE "cmake ")
set(MY_CMAKE_FLAGS CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ENABLE_SSL ENABLE_LUA ENABLE_SSH ENABLE_SNMP MYSQL_USER MYSQL_PASS MYSQL_HOST MYSQL_DB FULL_FEATURES USE_COVERAGE)
FOREACH(cmd_line_loop IN ITEMS ${MY_CMAKE_FLAGS})
    if(${cmd_line_loop})
        STRING(CONCAT USED_CMD_LINE ${USED_CMD_LINE} "-D"  ${cmd_line_loop} "=" ${${cmd_line_loop}} " ")
    endif()
ENDFOREACH(cmd_line_loop)
STRING(CONCAT USED_CMD_LINE ${USED_CMD_LINE} " .. ")
#store to a file aka "config.status"
FILE(WRITE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config.status ${USED_CMD_LINE} )
```

creates a file config.status in the build folder - containing all set cmake params.

pro:

- seems to solve my problem
- seems to work on subsequent cmake calls

con:

- unable to set chmod on `FILE(write` ? the variable
- `MY_CMAKE_FLAGS`contains the known flags - needs to be manually
  updated if a new flag is added

regards

Comment: This is an excellent question--one that I have had for a couple of years but have not asked on StackOverflow. I do not think there is a way to get the set of -D flags used when invoking cmake. The answer sakra gave below shows how to get see the exact commands that are a result of the cmake invocation, but that does not give you the args used for the cmake configure invocation. A correct answer is more difficult than one might expect since a user may continually reconfigure a cmake build directory using `cmake -Danotherflag=value .`.

Comment: thats sad!
in fact i really love cmake, it solves like 3.5mio issues (i learned to live with) from autotools - but the lack of getting user supplied commandline flags, is really bad.

Comment: see my edited question - it alteast for me solves my issue (in a not perfect way anyway)

Comment: What about the generated CMakeCache.txt it contain the used flags...

Answer (score 2):

Cmake does not give you easy way to list all used -D flags (defines). However, for correctly written CMakeLists, it is not needed to know the full command line with all -D flags to change one particular define/option.

Consider this snipplet:

```
SET(my_var_1 TRUE CACHE BOOL "my var 1")
SET(my_var_2 TRUE CACHE BOOL "my var 2")

message(STATUS "my_var_1 ${my_var_1}")
message(STATUS "my_var_2 ${my_var_2}")
```

First cmake invocation:

```
>cmake .. -Dmy_var_1=FALSE
-- my_var_1 FALSE
-- my_var_2 TRUE
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: out
```

Second cmake invocation:

```
>cmake  .. -Dmy_var_2=FALSE
-- my_var_1 FALSE
-- my_var_2 FALSE
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: out
```

Note that `my_var_1=FALSE` even it is not explicitely stated (taken from cache)

Comment: thx for your answer
i know that features, based on the cmakecache
but for my question its more like - i have a build folder on server A - and want to compile the source on a different server from scratch (in autotools days - i  just downloaded the source to the new server - copied the configure command from config status, and run this on the new server)

see my edited question - this is actually a way i can live with

Comment: Given your most recent edit where you say you can live with keeping track of ``MY_CMAKE_FLAGS``, you should consider the cmake module [FeatureSummary](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/FeatureSummary.html).

Comment: may be CMakeCache.txt could be copied to the new project build dir and running cmake again will take the cache file in consideration...

Answer (score 1):

One feature that may be helpful is turning on the flag `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` in the project's CMake cache. During build, this will make CMake generate a JSON file `compile_commands.json` in the binary directory that contains the exact compiler calls for all translation units.

Comment: thx for your answer, and nice to know about the `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` but it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at what is done in the [bootstrap](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/bootstrap#L1650) script in CMake's source code:

```
# Write our default settings to Bootstrap${_cmk}/InitialCacheFlags.cmake.
echo '
# Generated by '"${cmake_source_dir}"'/bootstrap
# Default cmake settings.  These may be overridden any settings below.
set (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "'"${cmake_prefix_dir}"'" CACHE PATH "Install path prefix, prepended onto install directories." FORCE)
set (CMAKE_DOC_DIR "'"${cmake_doc_dir}"'" CACHE PATH "Install location for documentation (relative to prefix)." FORCE)
set (CMAKE_MAN_DIR "'"${cmake_man_dir}"'" CACHE PATH "Install location for man pages (relative to prefix)." FORCE)
set (CMAKE_DATA_DIR "'"${cmake_data_dir}"'" CACHE PATH "Install location for data (relative to prefix)." FORCE)
' > "${cmake_bootstrap_dir}/InitialCacheFlags.cmake"

[...]

"${cmake_bootstrap_dir}/cmake" "${cmake_source_dir}" "-C${cmake_bootstrap_dir}/InitialCacheFlags.cmake" "-G${cmake_bootstrap_generator}" ${cmake_options} ${cmake_bootstrap_system_libs} "$@"
```

The `boostrap` script is generating a `InitialCacheFlags.cmake` file and is then preloading it with the [cmake -C](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake.1.html) option.

And - if you additionally want to output the values to `stdout` - this initial-cache CMake script also accepts `message()` commands besides the `set(... CACHE)` commands.

See also [How to store CMake build settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588517/how-to-store-cmake-build-settings)