# Get cmake options from program

Tags: c++, c, cmake

How can I get CMake options used for building from within a program?

E.g. I would like to use this:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Build options: " << BUILD_OPTIONS << std::endl;
}
```

`BUILD_OPTIONS` would contain a string with all options passed to `cmake`, like:

```
cmake -DOPT1 -DOPT3
```

with `CMakeLists.txt` defined as follows:

```
option(OPT1 "option 1" OFF)
option(OPT2 "option 2" OFF)
option(OPT3 "option 3" OFF)
```

The desired output of such program:

```
Build options: OPT1=ON OPT3=ON
```

(`OPT2` skipped, as it is not defined explicitly and equal to default value)

Comment: Well, you have 3 **separate problems**: 1. Extract parameters passed to `cmake`. 2. Combine that parameters into the string like `OPT1=ON OPT3=ON`. 3. Pass resulted string to the C program as a macro. Which problem you have already solved and which you cannot?

Comment: @Tsyvarev None yet, I was hoping someone already had the same requirements ;-) Your right though, this can be broken down into smaller steps - number 2 and 3 seem to be quite straightforward. However I didn't find a way to list all CMake options so far...

Comment: "I didn't find a way to list all CMake options so far." - It seems there is not easy way for doing this. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205986/how-to-capture-cmake-command-line-arguments) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870975/cmake-get-the-used-commandline-flags-d).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible to find out if an option has been specified explicitly or not.

The proposed solution will show all option values as specified in a CMake string variable. It consists of 3 steps:

- Combine the option values to a string in `CMakeLists.txt`
- Let CMake generate a source file with placeholder substitution.
- Compile and link your program with the generated file.

In `CMakeLists.txt` add e.g.

```
set(BUILD_OPTIONS "OPT1=${OPT1} OPT2=${OPT2} OPT3=${OPT3}")

configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build_options.c.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/build_options.c @ONLY)
```

Manually created files:

`build_options.c.in`

```
#include "build_options.h"

const char *BUILD_OPTIONS = "@BUILD_OPTIONS@";
```

`build_options.h`

```
#ifndef BUILD_OPTIONS_H_
#define BUILD_OPTIONS_H_

extern const char *BUILD_OPTIONS;

#endif /* BUILD_OPTIONS_H_ */
```

`CMake` will generate `build_options.c`

```
#include "build_options.h"

const char *BUILD_OPTIONS = "OPT1=ON OPT2=OFF OPT3=ON";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) command with 'cmakedefine' feaure. This is capable to generate something very similar what autotools do i.e. config.h with all enabled/disabled features.
The final string may be concatenated from particular sub-string depending if CMake option defined.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the program itself was compiled using the CMakeLists.txt file, you could write something along these lines:

```
option (OPT1 “option 1” OFF)
option (OPT2 “option 2” OFF)

if (OPT1)
    add_definitions (-DOPT1_ENABLED)
endif(OPT1)

if (OPT2)
    add_definitions (-DOPT2_ENABLED)
endif(OPT2)
```

Then in your program:

```
int main(void)
{
    std::cout << “Build options: “;
#ifdef OPT1_ENABLED
    std::cout << “OPT1=ON ”;
#else
    std::cout << “OPT1=OFF ”;
#endif /* OPT1 */

#ifdef OPT2_ENABLED
    std::cout << “OPT2=ON ”;
#else
    std::cout << “OPT2=OFF ”;
#endif /* OPT2 */

    std::cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I'm using the following approach, maybe someone fill find that useful. Instead of `option()` function I'm using custom `feature_option()`:

```
include(cmake/options.cmake)

feature_option(OPT1 "option 1" OFF)
feature_option(OPT2 "option 2" OFF)
feature_option(OPT3 "option 3" OFF)
```

which defines the option and also stores it on a list. Then it can be passed to the compiler via `ENABLED_FEATURES` define:

```
get_feature_list(feature_list)
message(STATUS "Enabled features: ${feature_list}")
target_compile_definitions(target PUBLIC "-DENABLED_FEATURES=\"${feature_list}\"")
```

Those functions are defined in separate `options.cmake` file, so they can be used in project consiting of multiple modules:

```
function(feature_option option_variable help_string) # optional argument: default_value
    option(${option_variable} ${help_string} ${ARGN})
    get_property(FEATURE_VARIABLE_LIST GLOBAL PROPERTY FEATURE_VARIABLE_LIST)
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY FEATURE_VARIABLE_LIST ${FEATURE_VARIABLE_LIST} ${option_variable})
endfunction()

function(get_feature_list output_variable)
    get_property(FEATURE_VARIABLE_LIST GLOBAL PROPERTY FEATURE_VARIABLE_LIST)
    foreach(option_variable ${FEATURE_VARIABLE_LIST})
        set(option_value "${${option_variable}}")
        if(${option_value})
            if(feature_list)
                set(feature_list "${feature_list},${option_variable}")
            else()
                set(feature_list "${option_variable}")
            endif()
        endif()
    endforeach()
    set(${output_variable} ${feature_list} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to pass a list of all defines to a program in a single string using generator expressions:

```
target_compile_options(target PRIVATE "-DENABLED_FEATURES=\"$<JOIN:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>,$<COMMA>>\"")
```

Using `target_compile_options` instead of `target_compile_definitions`, as the latter would cause infinite recursion.

In CMake 3.15 and newer it is possible to use `REMOVE_DUPLICATES` generator, if a single define may appear several times on a command line.